# How do you add Derived objects to a vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unique-ptr

How do you add different derived objects on to a vector of unique_ptr.
with a vector of pointers i would create the item then a base pointer the to object and pass the pointer to be added, but make_unique dosn't take a pointer and i dont want to make overloaded functions for each type of derived objs.

```
class Base{...};

class Item:public Base{...};

Add_Item(Base* thing)
{   
    vec.push_back(thing);
}

//Problem with this is i have multiple derived objs and would rather have 1 Add_Item instead of multiple Add_Item functions.(if possible)
Add_Item(Item thing)
{   //this runs,but i lose anything that was in Item class
    vec.push_back(make_unique<Base>(thing));
}
```

/----------------------------------

follow up question, can you have a vector of unique_ptr inside another.
i have tried this, (both ways you guys have shown me, with template Add_Item function and item Add_Item function). but both produced errors.

```
class Item: public Item
{  vector<unique_ptr<Base>>inv }

Item bag;
Item n_bag;
bag.Add_Item<I>(n_bag);
```

follow up follow up, no you cant, any recommendation for what kind of smart pointer to use

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I have a follow up question, is it possible to have a vector of unique_ptr inside another vector of unique_ptr?

Comment: An important note to this question and the answers. **It's important to make the base class destructor virtual.** Normal compilation will not warn you if you forget. But it will result in a memory leak.

Answer (score 6):

`unique_ptr<T>` has a constructor that moves from a `unique_ptr<U>` of a different type `U` as long as the pointer to the second type is implicitly convertible to the pointer to the first type and `U` is not an array type. So just use `vec.push_back(make_unique<Item>(thing));`. See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ddafecd03734ffd).

To accept everything derived from `Base`, use a template:

```
template <typename D>
void AddItem(const D& thing) {
    vec.push_back(make_unique<D>(thing));
}
```

If `D` is not derived from `Base`, you get a compile error at the `push_back`.

Comment: +1 but of course, one needs `std::make_unique`, which is not part of C++11.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, the OP used that in their code, so I'm happy to assume that it's available.

Comment: @TC answer would be even better (as consultants say) if that clarifying comment was included, i.e. assumptions stated explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make your `AddItem()` method a template method, so that you do not have to write a different function for each derived class. Modifying your existing implementation:

```
template <typename DERIVED>
void
AddItem (const DERIVED &thing)
{
    vec.push_back(make_unique<DERIVED>(thing));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `std::make_unique()` helper function creates a new object of the given type. In your case this is a `Base` object, which is not what you want.

Instead, you can manually construct the desired `std::unique_ptr`:

```
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Item(thing)));
```

This creates a new `Item`, and then constructs a `unique_ptr<Base>` from that.

Alternatively you could also simple create a `unique_ptr<Item>` and let implicit conversion convert it to a base pointer when you add it to the vector:

```
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Item>(thing));
```